# Bypass anti scraper that changes the suffix of a url when looping through many urls

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've built a scraper that has a parent url and many children. I built a list with the urls of the children and am looping through it -all are https-. However, when I get to the second object of the loop, it adds a suffix (?Nao=0) and scrapes the parent again.

I illustrate it below:

```
links_products = ['https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=24',
                  'https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=48', 
                  'https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=72']


from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/chromedriver')

for i in links_products:
    driver.get(i) 
    print(driver.current_url)
```

The result -which adds '*?Nao=0*'- at the end of each url is.

```
https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=24?Nao=0
https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=48?Nao=0
https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=72?Nao=0
```

I've tried adding

```
driver.execute_script('window.history.go(-1)')
driver.refresh()
print(driver.current_url)
```

Then it prints the urls I actually want to scrape:

```
https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=24
https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=48
https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=72
```

**But only scrapes three times the parent of the three links above**, namely:
`https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r`

Any suggestions on how to bypass this issue?

**ps. it is the same if I go through the loop, as above described, or by clicking on the button "next". It all comes back to the parent.**

Answer (score 0):

Just try with these urls:

```
https://www.target.com/c/grocery-deals/-/N-5xt0rZ55e6uZ55e69Z55e6tZ5tdv0r&Nao=0?Nao=24
```

Keep the Nao=0 and modify the one after ?Nao=...

It worked for me

Comment: It didn't... After some iterations it "bugs" again...